# Canon mf8350cdn Printer installation in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, printing, canon

I have downloaded mf8350cdn Linux driver from Canon.  But how do I actually install it, for a printer connected to router/home network?  (Model number is not in the drop-down Canon "choose driver" list, although the model does appear in the "select device" list.)

Instructions followed; this was the output:

```
marilyn@marilyn-XPS-8500:~/Downloads/ron/linux-UFRII-drv-v331-usen/64-bit_Driver/Debian$ sudo apt-get -f install libglade2-0 libc6:i386 lib32z1 libxml2:i386 libjpeg62:i386 libstdc++6:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lib32z1 : Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 libc6:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 libstdc++6:i386 : Depends: gcc-5-base:i386 (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libxml2:i386 : Depends: libicu55:i386 (>= 55.1-1~) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: liblzma5:i386 (>= 5.1.1alpha+20120614) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: zlib1g:i386 (>= 1:1.2.3.3) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: xml-core:i386 but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Any assistance would be most appreciated.

Comment: Is it connected directly to your PC, or is it on the network?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

First, you'll need some prerequisites:

```
sudo apt-get -y install libglade2-0 libc6:i386 lib32z1 libxml2:i386 libjpeg62:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

Next, download the correct driver from [here](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/support-laser-printers-imageclass/color-imageclass-mf8350cdn) (you're looking for the Linux version, and it should download a file called `Linux_UFRII_PrinterDriver_V320_us_EN.tar.gz`)

Once it's finished downloading, open your Terminal, and the `cd` to the directory where you downloaded it.

Time to extract the downloaded file:

```
gunzip -c Linux_UFRII_PrinterDriver_V320_us_EN.tar.gz | tar xvf -
```

Then `cd` into the 64bit Debian Driver folder like this

```
cd Linux_UFRII_PrinterDriver_V320_us_EN/64-bit_Driver/Debian/
```

Finally, install the drivers:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```